# How to implement "order by" together with "group by" in query

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using `group by` clause and I also want to use `order by`. Can anyone tell me how can I can implement `order by` clause in the following query

```
SELECT 
   MIN(UR.REG_UNIQUE_ID) "ANUBANDH ID",
   MIN(UR.FIRM_NAME) "FIRM OF CONTRACTOR",
   MIN(UR.NAME) "NAME OF PROPRIETOR",
   MIN(CD.MOBILE)"MOBILE NUMBER",
   MIN(CD.EMAIL) EMAIL,
   MIN(UR.ADDRESS)|| ' ' || MIN(UR.ADDRESS2)  ADDRESS,
   MIN(UR.COR_ADDRESS1) || '' || MIN(UR.COR_ADDRESS2) AS "CORRESPONDING ADDRESS",
MIN(CASE
  WHEN MS.OIT_STATUS=1 THEN 'YES'
  ELSE 'NO'
END) "OYT ELIGIBILITY",
LISTAGG(UUC.NAME, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY RC.CIRCLE_RATE_ID ASC) "CIRCLE"
--MIN(UUC.NAME)
FROM CONTRACTOR_DETAIL CD
JOIN USER_REGISTRATION UR 
    ON CD.CONTRACTOR_ID=UR.CONTRACTOR_ID
JOIN MANAGE_SERVICES MS
    ON MS.CONTRACTOR_ID=UR.CONTRACTOR_ID
JOIN RC_CONTRACTOR RC
    ON RC.CONTRACTOR_ID=UR.CONTRACTOR_ID
JOIN CIRCLE_RATE CR
    ON CR.CIRCLE_RATE_ID = RC.CIRCLE_RATE_ID
JOIN UAM_USER.CIRCLE UUC
    ON CR.CIRCLE_ID=UUC.CIRCLE_ID
WHERE UR.REG_UNIQUE_ID IS NOT NULL
    AND UR.PAYMENT_STATUS=1
    AND MS.REG_CLASS_ID IN (5,6,7)
GROUP BY UR.CONTRACTOR_ID;
```

Comment: on which column u need order by

Comment: Just add an `order by` ?

Comment: UR.REG_UNIQUE_ID

Comment: just add Order by UR.REG_UNIQUE_ID after the group by

Comment: Just add an `ORDER BY` clause to your statement - since it is not part of the group by you will need to include the aggregate function `ORDER BY MIN(UR.REG_UNIQUE_ID)`, or you will need to order by the column alias -  `ORDER BY "ANUBANDH ID"`

Comment: It will throw error ..."sql command not properly ended"

Comment: Ok Gareth... I got your point it fixed the query output, thanks so much for suggesstion, its just a silly mistake i made lol..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put a order by clause in last of the query after group by clause

```
SELECT 
 MIN(UR.REG_UNIQUE_ID) "ANUBANDH ID",
 MIN(UR.FIRM_NAME) "FIRM OF CONTRACTOR",
 MIN(UR.NAME) "NAME OF PROPRIETOR",
 MIN(CD.MOBILE)"MOBILE NUMBER",
 MIN(CD.EMAIL) EMAIL,
 MIN(UR.ADDRESS)|| ' ' || MIN(UR.ADDRESS2)  ADDRESS,
 MIN(UR.COR_ADDRESS1) || '' || MIN(UR.COR_ADDRESS2) AS "CORRESPONDING 
 ADDRESS",
 MIN(CASE
 WHEN MS.OIT_STATUS=1 THEN 'YES'
 ELSE 'NO'
 END) "OYT ELIGIBILITY",
 LISTAGG(UUC.NAME, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY RC.CIRCLE_RATE_ID ASC) 
 "CIRCLE"
 --MIN(UUC.NAME)
FROM CONTRACTOR_DETAIL CD
JOIN USER_REGISTRATION UR 
   ON CD.CONTRACTOR_ID=UR.CONTRACTOR_ID
JOIN MANAGE_SERVICES MS
   ON MS.CONTRACTOR_ID=UR.CONTRACTOR_ID
JOIN RC_CONTRACTOR RC
   ON RC.CONTRACTOR_ID=UR.CONTRACTOR_ID
JOIN CIRCLE_RATE CR
   ON CR.CIRCLE_RATE_ID = RC.CIRCLE_RATE_ID
JOIN UAM_USER.CIRCLE UUC
   ON CR.CIRCLE_ID=UUC.CIRCLE_ID
WHERE UR.REG_UNIQUE_ID IS NOT NULL
 AND UR.PAYMENT_STATUS=1
 AND MS.REG_CLASS_ID IN (5,6,7)
GROUP BY UR.CONTRACTOR_ID
ORDER BY MIN(UR.REG_UNIQUE_ID);
```

Comment: Add a line or two to explain what you have modified. Also, formatting the query would make it better.

Comment: sure i will make the change

Comment: thank you all of you for your kind help and suggestions